# Laying out a collection of strings in columns

Tags: java, collections

I have a list of strings that I want to display in an HTML table spread as evenly as possible across a specified number of columns.

```
public String toHtmlTable(Collection<String> values, int columns) {
    // TODO
}
```

I want the strings to be displayed like this:

```
A    E    I
B    F    J
C    G
D    H

(i.e. "<table><tr><td>A</td><td>E</td><td>I</td></tr>...</table>")
```

I don't want this:

```
A    B    C
D    E    F
G    H    I
J
```

What's a good way to do it?

Comment: Any reason it needs to be a (single) table? That'll cause unintuitive behavior when selecting text or using the tab key to pass focus to the next cell.

Comment: Each item is unrelated to the others (and is actually a link), so there's no need to support selecting text. I'll use `tabindex` to make sure tabbing works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

some codes may give some help:

I am bit lazy, two things are not done yet:

- the `<table></table>` tags are  not added. this is easy.
- empty   `<td></td>` was not handled.

code:

```
public void tt() {
    // you could ignore the ImmutableList stuff, it just prepares the string list, nothing more.
    final List<String> l = ImmutableList.of("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j");
    final int col = 3;
    final int size = l.size();
    final int n = size / col;
    final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        int k = i;
        sb.append("<tr>\n");
        while (k < size) {
            sb.append("<td>" + l.get(k) + "</td>");
            k += n + 1;
        }
        sb.append("\n</tr>\n");
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

output:

```
<tr>
<td>a</td><td>e</td><td>i</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>b</td><td>f</td><td>j</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>c</td><td>g</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>d</td><td>h</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table has `n` columns and you have `x` number of strings, you end up needing

`m = ceiling(x/n)` rows. So what you do is when outputting a line of html, just offset your variables correspondingly. Your first line of output should look like this:

```
arr[0]    arr[m]        arr[2m]        arr[3m]      ....     arr[nm]
```

then the next lines would be:

```
arr[1]    arr[m+1]      arr[2m+1]      arr[3m+1]    ....     arr[nm+1]
arr[2]    arr[m+2]      arr[2m+2]      arr[3m+2]    ....     arr[nm+2]
....
arr[m-1]  arr[2m-1]     arr[3m-1]      arr[4m-11]   ....     arr[(n+1)m-1]
```

You can figure out how to code nested loops to output this, it's not too difficult.

Each line is represented like this:

```
arr[i]    arr[m+i]      arr[2m+i]      arr[3m+i]    ....     arr[nm+i]
```

with `i` going from `0`to `(m-1)`.

I hope this helps.